# NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor not working when added to an object in MAUI 8.0

Tags: mvvm, maui, community-toolkit-mvvm

I am trying to disable an XAML button until the form is valid, at initial load it is disabled but not enabled on the model validation pass.

Here is my code

```cs
public class LoginRequest
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public sealed partial class LoginViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty] [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(LoginCommand))]
    private LoginRequest _form;
     
    bool IsFormValid()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Form.Email) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Form.Password);
    }
     
    [RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(IsFormValid))]
    async Task Login()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

```xml
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModels.Account"
    x:Class="MyProject.Pages.Account.LoginPage"
    x:TypeArguments="vm:LoginViewModel"
    x:DataType="vm:LoginViewModel">
     
    <Entry Placeholder="Email"
        Text="{x:Binding Form.Email, Mode=TwoWay}">
    </Entry>
     
    <Entry Placeholder="Password"
        Text="{x:Binding Form.Password, Mode=TwoWay}">
    </Entry>
    
    <Button Text="Login" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}">
    </Button>
```

When I add individual properties at my ViewModel its working as expected but to an object.

```cs
[ObservableProperty]
[NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(LoginCommand))]
private string email;
    
[ObservableProperty]
[NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(LoginCommand))]
private string password;
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you expecting that the command's executability changes when the `Email` or `Password` properties change? Because with your current code it will only work when you change the reference of the `Form` property, but not its values.

Comment: Yes, I expect the command's executability change as `Email` or `Password` changes in the `UI`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code only modifies the Property of the Form instance instead of changing the value of Form itself.

So, if you want to  get notified when a Property of an Object changes, you may try the following way,

First, also make the `Email` and `Password` to be an `ObservableProperty`.

```
public partial class LoginRequest :ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    public string email;

    [ObservableProperty]
    public string password;
}
```

Second, ObservableObject has a PropertyChanged EventHandler, which will occur when a Property has changed. So in your viewmodel, register and implement the PropertyChanged event handler for the Form instance.

```
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        Form = new LoginRequest();
        Form.PropertyChanged += Form_PropertyChanged;
    }

    private void Form_PropertyChanged(object? sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //this will invoke each time Email or Password change
        loginCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();
    }
```

Hope it helps!